# how do you pass an httpcontext object to a web service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, service

How do you pass an httpcontext.current object to a web service and use that object in the service, I get an error saying that it is expecting a string - surly this must be possible?

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols

<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class WebService
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Sub doThis(ByVal HC As HttpContext)
        'do something
    End Sub
End Class


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim s As test2.WebService = New test2.WebService
    s.doThis(HttpContext.Current)
End Sub
```

Comment: This must be done with dependency injection

Comment: do you have an example? thanks

Answer (score 3):

The HttpContext is not serilazible, so it can't be sent as a string.
HttpContext is an complex object with other complex properties, so it would be rather big if you would serialize it (which means it would be alot slower sending the data).

I believe it's better to encapsulate the information you need in a custom class instead and send that to the service.

That is, create a class with simple types that can be serialized (string, int, double, etc.) and fill it with the information you need.

Comment: @Hello-World I've updated the answer, not quite sure what you wanted me to explain more =)

Comment: The idea of encapsulation is a good one, especially if you only need a couple of really simple properties.  But assuming you need something more complex like `HttpContext.Current.Request` you are still going to be stuck.  What's the aversion to just using `ByRef`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass an `HttpContext` `ByVal`.  `ByVal` means by value, which means that the `HttpContext`'s value needs to be copied in order to be passed to your method.  Since it's a [complex] object, you can't do that.  Instead you need to pass it `ByRef`, which means pass a reference to the object to your method and work off of that reference.